# Problems translating objects

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

i am currently experiencing problems in translating revit files, either in new buckets or in older ones. I upload the file, then start the translation, after some progress i get a message "translation failed". I tried different revit versions, different files, using the VSCode Forge extension, using OSS bucket tool...nothing changes.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: please share the manifest response, it should have more information on why it's failing

Comment: Here's the object manifest:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WD3YV93dgz9ofgns_4T7rvK4vKpkTr7k/view?usp=sharing
everything seems working fine, i see the object viewables in the browser, but when i try to preview the derivatives i get 404 error...

Comment: i tried again with forge bucket tools, the translation process starts, then the final response is a 500 internal server error

Comment: 'but when i try to preview the derivatives i get 404 error' can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Initially, i can see the derivatives (2d views and 3Ds) just like i set them in Revit (puplish settings), so everything seems to be working fine. Then, when i try to preview the derivatives in the Forge VStudio extension, i get "404 file not found".
Then i go to oss manager, enter the app credentials, go to the bucket anf click on the derivatives, and instead of retrievine the hierarchy, the tool trigger a translation, just like the derivatives were not there...)

Comment: Are you also using the OSS Manager / VSCode extension to upload the file or only using them for translation?

Comment: Tried upload+translate using the same tool, with both tools

Comment: I find the problems with translation seem to happen with new buckets, while translation persists on buckets i created before. 
Another problem rises, however, when triggering a translation generating master view. 
In this screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kYoyFhwggmtZaW9FqASdLtc3Q-sSVlVA/view?usp=sharing i have a building with 1133 rooms, but only level 0 rooms are translated. Here's the manifest:https://drive.google.com/file/d/17WjwnBUPpMwDJm6QMk4aLw7FB4DjfU0M/view?usp=sharing, and the derivative:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tApEGUq2zS26MkUe1tu-z03Pq2dDo1RM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There was a regression on our side and the problematic deployment was rolled back last night. Could you please try translating your files one more time? If the issue persists, please schedule a 30min chat with me or one of my colleagues on https://calendly.com/autodeskforge, and we can take a closer look at it.

Comment: Thank you, i tried again and everything seems to be working fine